# Download de imagem svg para apresentar em ImageView de Android como?

Tags: java, android, json

Tenho uma api https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all que me retorna um json em Android. Esse json esta binded a uma classe usando Jackson. Mas preciso de usar o url que esta contido no json que é uma imagem svg. Quero usar essa imagem para apresentar a imagem na minha custom listview mas não consigo converter de forma alguma esse svg para uma imagem valida.

Já testei varias bibliotecas como svg-android, androidsvg1.2, glide, testei samples, tentei converter svg para png usando a biblioteca svg2png e nada funciona, em desespero ainda tentei usar a biblioteca da squared Picasso, mas obviamente que não ia funcionar pois a biblioteca não tem essa compatibilidade com imagens svg.

Já estou nisto á mais de 8horas por isso já deu para testar quase tudo o que está desnecessariamente espalhado pela internet... agradecia imenso uma mãosinha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), com alguns ajustes e com a ajuda do [AndroidSVG](http://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/), dá suporte ao carregamento de SVG. Tem [um exemplo no repositório deles](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/master/samples/svg) que mostra como. Vou reproduzir o código atual para a posterioridade:

Adicione as dependências adequadas (verificar versões):

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.1'
```

É preciso criar um `ResourceDecoder` pra converter um `InputStream` para `SVG`.

```
/**
 * Decodes an SVG internal representation from an {@link InputStream}.
 */
public class SvgDecoder implements ResourceDecoder<InputStream, SVG> {

  @Override
  public boolean handles(@NonNull InputStream source, @NonNull Options options) {
    // TODO: Can we tell?
    return true;
  }

  public Resource<SVG> decode(@NonNull InputStream source, int width, int height,
      @NonNull Options options)
      throws IOException {
    try {
      SVG svg = SVG.getFromInputStream(source);
      return new SimpleResource<>(svg);
    } catch (SVGParseException ex) {
      throw new IOException("Cannot load SVG from stream", ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Um `ResourceTranscoder` para converter de `SVG` para `Picture`:

```
/**
 * Convert the {@link SVG}'s internal representation to an Android-compatible one
 * ({@link Picture}).
 */
public class SvgDrawableTranscoder implements ResourceTranscoder<SVG, PictureDrawable> {
  @Override
  public Resource<PictureDrawable> transcode(Resource<SVG> toTranscode, Options options) {
    SVG svg = toTranscode.get();
    Picture picture = svg.renderToPicture();
    PictureDrawable drawable = new PictureDrawable(picture);
    return new SimpleResource<>(drawable);
  }
}
```

Criar um novo módulo:

```
/**
 * Module for the SVG sample app.
 */
@GlideModule
public class SvgModule extends AppGlideModule {
  @Override
  public void registerComponents(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide,
      @NonNull Registry registry) {
    registry.register(SVG.class, PictureDrawable.class, new SvgDrawableTranscoder())
        .append(InputStream.class, SVG.class, new SvgDecoder());
  }

  // Disable manifest parsing to avoid adding similar modules twice.
  @Override
  public boolean isManifestParsingEnabled() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

E um request listener:

```
/**
 * Listener which updates the {@link ImageView} to be software rendered, because
 * {@link com.caverock.androidsvg.SVG SVG}/{@link android.graphics.Picture Picture} can't render on
 * a hardware backed {@link android.graphics.Canvas Canvas}.
 */
public class SvgSoftwareLayerSetter implements RequestListener<PictureDrawable> {

  @Override
  public boolean onLoadFailed(GlideException e, Object model, Target<PictureDrawable> target,
      boolean isFirstResource) {
    ImageView view = ((ImageViewTarget<?>) target).getView();
    view.setLayerType(ImageView.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onResourceReady(PictureDrawable resource, Object model,
      Target<PictureDrawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
    ImageView view = ((ImageViewTarget<?>) target).getView();
    view.setLayerType(ImageView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Consegui carregar a bandeira do Brasil utilizando o endereço que vem do seu JSON:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://restcountries.eu/data/bra.svg");

GlideApp.with(this)
    .as(PictureDrawable.class)
    .listener(new SvgSoftwareLayerSetter())
    .load(uri).into(imageViewNet);
```

[image: Imagem carregada]

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou, não tinha feito a combinação de ambos.